# How it is possible for entropy of universe to increase during reversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, reversibility

To calculate the entropy change of the universe when a closed system undergoes an irreversible process, one must choose a reversible process and calculate the following integral

$$\Delta S=\int \frac{\delta Q_\mathrm{rev}}{T}$$

However, it contradicts the fact that during reversible processes, $\Delta S=0$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: On a general note: thermodynamics doesn't say anything about the entropy of the universe. It only says that the entropy of something else (what Bob calls "surroundings" in his answer) must increase. If you are trying to apply the definition of entropy to "the universe", then you are running into a contradiction because there is nothing else. The universe is not "surrounded" by anything by definition. Philosophically you can try a workaround by saying "visible universe", but since the universe is not even energy conserving, even the first law of TD falls away, so why not the second?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/743208/how-can-the-entropy-change-in-entropy-of-reversible-and-irreversible-process-b

Comment: @Themis This is different. I understand that entropy is a state function but when one uses a reversible process to calculate the entropy change of the universe, doesn't it contradict the fact reversible processes should have no change of entropy in the universe? This is where I am confused.

Comment: Would you at least be able to determine the entropy change of the system for the irreversible process path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How it is possible for entropy of universe to increase during
> reversible process?

It's not.

Your equation is for the change in entropy of the system only. The change in entropy of the system for a reversible process can be zero, less than zero, or greater than zero depending on the process. The change in entropy of the universe is the sum of the change in entropy of the system and the surroundings.

For a reversible process

$$\Delta S_{univ}=\Delta S_{system}+\Delta S_{surroundings}=0$$

or

$$\Delta S_{system}=-\Delta S_{surroundings}$$

So if the change in entropy of the system is greater than zero for a reversible process, the change in entropy of the surroundings will be less than zero by the same amount for a total change of zero. For example, the change in entropy of the system for a reversible isothermal expansion is $+Q/T$ whereas the change for the surroundings is $-Q/T$ for a total entropy change of zero.

> I feel uncomfortable by the fact one can determine the entropy change
> of an irreversible process by selecting a reversible path. If a path
> is reversible, there should be no entropy change in universe.

If the *actual* path is reversible, then there will be no change in the entropy of the universe. If the *actual* path is irreversible, then there will be an increase in entropy of the universe, where the change in entropy of the universe is the sum of the changes in entropy of the system plus the surroundings. But the change in entropy of the *system* will be the same for a reversible and irreversible path between the same two equilibrium states since entropy is a state function.

Selecting a reversible path does not "replace" the irreversible process. Its only purpose is to enable calculation of the entropy change of the system using the definition of entropy change

$$\Delta S_{sys}=\int_1^2 \frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}\tag{1}$$

An example is calculating the entropy change for the free adiabatic expansion of an ideal gas (Joule expansion). The process is irreversible with the initial and final temperatures being the same, $T_{2}=T_{1}$, and where $P_{2}V_{2}=P_{1}V_{1}$. Although any reversible path can be used, the logical choice is a reversible isothermal expansion. The change in entropy of the system using eq (1) above is then

$$\Delta S_{sys}=R\ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}$$

Since the actual irreversible process is adiabatic, $\Delta S_{surr}=0$ making $\Delta S_{univ}=\Delta S_{sys}+\Delta S_{surr}= R\ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}$ or $\Delta S_{univ}\gt 0$. *The increase in entropy is due to entropy generated within the system*.

If the actual process was a reversible isothermal expansion, where heat transfer can occur between the system and surroundings (in contrast to an adiabatic expansion where heat transfer cannot occur), then the change in entropy of the surroundings will be $\Delta S_{surr}= -R\ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}$ and therefore $\Delta S_{univ}=0$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For more context, I was trying to understand [this article](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/) about calculating entropy change in irreversible processes. My problem is that I do not understand why it is possible to use reversible processes to calculate the entropy change of the universe.

Comment: What, in particular, do you not understand about the article?  note that they use the reversible process to calculate the change in entropy of the system, not the universe.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like one can calculate the entropy change of the universe by assuming that the universe is in contact with some external thermal reservoir. By using a reversible process, the total entropy change of universe+reservoir is zero?

Comment: I’m not sure I follow you. The “universe” is by definition everything. It makes no sense to say the universe is in contact with something else (external thermal reservoir)

Comment: Consider an isolated system made of two objects of temperature $T_1$ and $T_2$ in thermal contact with each other. When $T_1>T_2$, object 1 spontaneously gives heat $Q$ to object 2. Assuming that the process is reversible, the change of entropy of this composite system at this instant is $\Delta S=\frac{-Q}{T_1}+\frac{Q}{T_2}$. Is it wrong to interpret $\Delta S$ here as universe entropy change?

Comment: @JimmyYang But the process is not reversible because it occurs over a finite temperature difference within the isolated system. You can’t have two different temperatures at a single location (in this case the contact surface between the objects).  There is in reality a temperature gradient. But in order to apply the entropy definition to the two parts of the system individually, you assume a reversible heat transfer for each  object.

Comment: Since the system is isolated, the entropy change of the surroundings has to be zero. So we have $\Delta S_{univ}=\Delta S_{sys}+\Delta S_{surr}=\biggl (\frac{-Q}{T_1}+\frac{Q}{T_2}\biggr )+0$. And then since $T_{1}\gt T_{2}$, we have $\Delta S_{univ}\gt 0$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by using a reversible process (ie. applying the definition $dS=Q/T$) to determine the entropy change of the universe. I do not understand why we need to assume reversible heat transfer to each object.

Comment: @JimmyYang Because $dS=\frac{\delta Q}{T}$ is defined for a reversible process only.

Comment: Right but if we assume a reversible process, then it should be $\Delta S_{univ}=0$?

Comment: @JimmyYang Choosing a reversible path between the same two equilibrium states to replace the irreversible path in order to calculate the entropy change doesn't make the actual process reversible.  I’ll look for an example to show you.

Comment: @JimmyYang Are you familiar with how to calculate the change in entropy for the free adiabatic expansion of an ideal gas into a vacuum (which is an irreversible process)?

Comment: Yes, you mean Joule expansion? How does replacing an irreversible path with reversible one does not make the process reversible?

Comment: Do you agree the joule expansion is an irreversible process and if so how do you calculate the entropy generated in the gas?

Comment: @Bob_D looking at the underlying confusion of terms, definitions, concepts, etc., in the question and the following comments, (and I also was one of those completely confused when I studied this the first of many times...) I hope you also see now the superiority and simplicity of teaching/introducing the subject the way Carnot envisioned it 200 years ago and Bronsted tried to follow suit a 100 years ago, and forget Clausius (and Caratheodory)!

Comment: @JimmyYang Let me try a different approach. Consider two equilibrium states, 1 and 2.  I want to determine the change in entropy of the system between those two states. Since entropy, like internal energy, is a state property, the change in entropy of the system between the two states must be independent of the path, reversible or irreversible,  taken between the two states.  Do you agree so far?

Comment: Yes, I agree but I feel uncomfortable by the fact one can determine the entropy change of an irreversible process by selecting a reversible path. If a path is reversible, there should be no entropy change in universe.

Comment: @JimmyYang If the ACTUAL path  is reversible, then there will be no change in the entropy of the universe. If the ACTUAL path is irreversible, then there will be an increase in entropy of the universe, where the change in entropy of the universe is the sum of the changes in entropy of the system plus the surroundings. But the change in entropy of the SYSTEM will be the same for a reversible and irreversible path between the same two equilibrium states. It's getting late here (US east coast) but tomorrow I will update my answer to include some concrete examples to demonstrate this.

Comment: @JimmyYang See update to my answer.